# How to read Values inside the XML tag values using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can I get this value **timestamp="1533209779825"** from the XML string below using PHP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<response>
    <status returnCode="SUCCESS" method="/testcustomer.xml" timestamp="1533209779825" messageArg="">Success</status>
</response>
```

When read using simplexml_load_string method, it instead returns

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [status] => Success)

Comment: Show us your code. Otherwise we waste time with a session of 20 questions

Comment: `$timestamp = (string) $object->status['timestamp'];` ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post and added the XML code as an Image link.
Everytime I post the XML code stack overflow  makes it disappear

Comment: I'd already edited your post to show the XML - posting code as images makes it much harder for us to help you

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution and your solution has worked for me